# PlayFramework Json validation boilerplate

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

Whenever I create POST method entry which accepts Json body, I have to write something like:

```
req.body.validate[SomeBodyClassRepresentation].fold(
  errors => logErrorAndReturnBadRequest(),
  valid => handleRequest()
)
```

Is there any way to reduce that boilerplate, since handling malformed json body is almost always done the same way? 
I'm thinking about something like some ActionBuilder, which will proper work with different Request types.

Comment: The tradition here is to post what **you have tried** before asking!

Answer (score 1):

You could make a method that wraps your error handling behavior, something like this:

```
def withParsedJsonRequest[T](actionBody: T => Future[Result])(
 implicit reads: Reads[T], req: Request[JsValue]): Future[Result] = {
  req.body.validate[T].fold(
    invalid => { Future.successful(BadRequest("An error occured...")) }, // do error handling here!
    valid => { actionBody(valid) })
}
```

and use it in `Action`s:

```
def bla = Action.async(parse.json) { implicit req =>
  withParsedJsonRequest[Bla] { b => 
    Future.successful(Ok)
  }
}
```

You have to pass implicit `Reads` of `T` (for parsing JSON) to the `withParsedJsonRequest` function, and also the `Request[JsValue]` (so you don't have to repeat it).

The callback function called "actionBody" is the meat of your action. It takes parsed `T` and does something with it.

I guess you could make a custom `Action` but why bother...

Comment: `withParsedJsonRequest` could also receive an 'invalid' function, with a default value

Answer (score 0):

If you have an implicit `Reads[T]` in scope, and agree to use Play's error handler (which you can somehow customize), there is a body parser that does just what you want:

```
def foo = Action(parse.json[T]) { request =>
  val body: T = request.body
  ...
}
```

Note however, that this returns a 400 if the `Content-Type` is not set to `application/json` (there is no equivalent with `tolerantJson`).